# Write greek language Rmarkdown pdf or html document

Tags: html, r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

I really need to write a Rmarkdown pdf document, I tried this in english version

```
 ---
title: "Report"
subtitle: "Company S.A."
output:
 bookdown::pdf_document2:
toc: true
number_sections: true
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{titling}
 - \pretitle{\begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{logo.png}\LARGE\\}
 - \posttitle{\end{center}}
---
```

and works just fine I have the pdf document that I want. When I try to write the same exact document in greek, It does't work anything it cannot recognize the greek language. so I tried this, but also did not work.

---

```
 header_includes:
    - \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    - \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
    - \newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
    - \newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
 title: "Φύλλο αναφοράς"
subtitle: "Εταρεία Α.Ε."
output:
bookdown::pdf_document2:
toc: true
number_sections: true
---

\gr Καλημερα
```

Does anyone know how tosolve this problem? I need two documents to write in greek one in html and one in pdf.

using this code

```
---
title: "\\gr Φύλλο αναφοράς"
subtitle: "\\gr Εταρεία Α.Ε."
 output:
 bookdown::pdf_document2:
toc: true
number_sections: true
keep_tex: true
header-includes:
 - \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
 - \newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
 - \newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
---

 \gr Καλημερα
```

it gives me this error

[image]

while using this code

```
---
 title: "Φύλλο αναφοράς"
 subtitle: "Εταρεία Α.Ε."
  output:
   bookdown::pdf_document2:
   toc: true
    number_sections: true
    keep_tex: true
    latex_engine: xelatex
    header-includes:
     - \usepackage{fontspec}
   - \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
   ---

   Καλημερα
```

it gives me this error

[image]

Comment: Consider switching to an unicode aware engine like lualatex or xelatex, makes dealing with exotic scripts much easier

Comment: I did it but it did not work!

Comment: In the last two code examples, the indention is wrong. Please compare them to the code I posted. For example the "output:" must not be indented.

Comment: ok i understood what you mean, i took both codes copy + paste in my Rmarkdown in R and they both gave me errors

Comment: The spaces/tabs in front of `output:` and all the other stuff in the header are important. You must not randomly change them.

Comment: yes i know in my rmarkdown they are correct such as you wrote them, but not working anything

Comment: and for the "Tex gyre heros" not found error: as I said in my answer, you need to replace it with a font you have available (or install the `tex-gyre` package)

Comment: You show them wrong in your question. We cannot know what you have in your real code. All the advice we can give is on what you show us.

Answer (score 2):

- you'll need to use your `\gr` macro also for your greek titles
- some of the indention of the header seemed to be wrong
- you can't use `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` because rmarkdown automatically loads the package with another option (and most of the time `utf8x` is anyway wrong)

---

```
---
title: "\\gr Φύλλο αναφοράς"
subtitle: "\\gr Εταρεία Α.Ε."
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
   - \newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
   - \newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
---

\gr Καλημερα
```

[image]

(corresponding rstudio project: https://rstudio.cloud/project/2490809)

Personally I would use lualatex or xelatex for non-latin texts:

```
---
title: "Φύλλο αναφοράς"
subtitle: "Εταρεία Α.Ε."
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
    keep_tex: true
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{fontspec}
   - \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
---

Καλημερα
```

[image]

(replace `TeX Gyre Heros` with whatever font you have available that includes all the characters you need)

Comment: @MariaProvelegiou Can you show the complete error message? (not in a comment, because there are no linebreaks)

Comment: @MariaProvelegiou I can't reproduce the error https://rstudio.cloud/project/2490809